# ggplot fails to plot time series when width is provided

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have below `ggplot` with time series data

```
library(ggplot2)
dat = data.frame('date' = as.Date(c('2000-01-01', '2001-01-01', '2002-01-01', '2003-01-01', '2004-01-01', '2005-01-01', '2000-01-01', '2001-01-01', '2002-01-01', '2003-01-01', '2004-01-01', '2005-01-01')), 'val' = 1:12, 'sep' = rep(c('sep1', 'sep2'), each = 6))
ggplot(dat, aes(x = date, y = val)) +
geom_bar(aes(fill = sep), stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge', width = 0.8) +
scale_x_date(date_labels =  "%Y")
```

With this I ma getting some strange plot

[image]

It looks that if I dont provide information `width = 0.8` then plot appears fine. Is there any way to adjust the width of each bar?

Comment: Hi @Brian its look like you just giving less width, try to give 100 or 200.

Comment: When your x-axis is `Date` class, then the standard unit is 1 day. So width = 0.8 is 80% of a day, about 19 hours, which is tiny on a multi-year scale. Either set the width **much** bigger or create a `factor` class `year` column and use that on the x-axis.

Comment: Based on the explanation of Gregor, simply use `width = 0.8 * 365`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rajan said right in the comments make your width bigger and you can use `date_breaks = "1 year"` to label al your bars like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat = data.frame('date' = as.Date(c('2000-01-01', '2001-01-01', '2002-01-01', '2003-01-01', '2004-01-01', '2005-01-01', '2000-01-01', '2001-01-01', '2002-01-01', '2003-01-01', '2004-01-01', '2005-01-01')), 'val' = 1:12, 'sep' = rep(c('sep1', 'sep2'), each = 6))
ggplot(dat, aes(x = date, y = val)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = sep), stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge', width = 100) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels =  "%Y") +
  labs(x = "Year")
```

Output:

[image]